# Two connected codes dont close each other

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the problem that those two codes not work as intended. start.bat should be called first and open another cmd window.
This works but the closing procedure does not.
it should close the other the other window if it closes itself

**start.bat:**

```
@echo off
set /a Sid = %RANDOM%
title %Sid%-Server
set /a Wid = %RANDOM%
start "%Wid%-WebSocket" cmd /k "%~dp0websocket/websocket.bat" %Sid%

set /a t = 1
:loop

REM set /p reload = "Do you want to reload after stopping: "
set /a reload = 0
php -S 192.168.2.117:80
echo "close Server"

if /I %reload% == %t% goto loop
taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq %Wid%-WebSocket" /T /F
```

**websocket.bat:**

```
@echo off
set /a t = 1
:loop

set /p reload = "Do you want to reload after stopping: "
php %~dp0ws.php
echo "close Websocket"

if /I %reload% == %t% goto loop
taskkill /FI "WindowTitle eq %Sid%-Server" /T /F
```

Maybe you can help me with this question. I allready searched a long time but nothing worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My first advice is that you learn what `Set` command's `/A` option is for. It is for performing arithmetic, and neither of your scripts is performing any. You should really change `set /a Sid = %RANDOM%` to `Set "Sid=%RANDOM%"`, `set /a Wid = %RANDOM%` to `Set "Wid=%RANDOM%"` ,`set /a t = 1` to `Set "t=1"`, and `set /a reload = 0` to `Set "reload=0"`. Also as you know that `%reload%` and `%t%` are numeric only, you should replace `if /I %reload% == %t% goto loop` with `If %reload% Equ %t% goto loop`.

Comment: thank you very much i try it. Only the ```set /a reload = 0``` is not so important. It was just for testing

Comment: another question is now that ```goto``` is now syntacticly wrong. Why?

Comment: But when i change the if back to ```==``` then only ```loop``` is wrong

Comment: The `goto` isn't syntactically wrong, your `set /p` command is! The syntax you've used currently requires that you use the correct variable name, **`%reload %`**, _(the spaces are included)_. To use the recommended syntax, change `set /p reload = "Do you want to reload after stopping: "`, to `Set /P "reload=Do you want to reload after stopping: "`.

Comment: oh ok im sorry for so dump questions but i just startet with cmd

Comment: Thank now it works like nothing happend. Thank you very much

Comment: It doesn't matter, how new you are to it, whatever you begin, you should always read the instructions. In this case the instructions for every command are already provided in your PC, _using the `/?` option_, without ever having to pick up a book, visit forums, watch videos, or type into a search engine.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the advice